# I have hosted a django application render on free server. It is working fine local machine but not working in render ,i have pushed all the code

Tags: django, github, django-templates, render

I have fetched NSE data from nse api and displayed  using chart js in django templates , everything fine in local machine , once i pushed the all code in render server it is showing like this .
This page isn’t workingsuperlogo-final.onrender.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 502.

I have uploaded the images please check and help me figure out the problem

Comment: I think you forget to attach image, as you mentioned in you questions. If possible try to attach error as a text instead of image.